# How to use standard validation data annotations with custom types?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

Is it possible to use the standard data annotations within the .NET framework (such as StringLength, RegularExpression, Required, etc.) with custom types?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
  class MyProperty<TValue>
   {
      public bool Reset { get; set; }
      public TValue Value { get; set; }
   }

   class MyClass
   {
      [Required]
      [StringLength(32)]
      MyProperty<string> Name { get; set; }

      [StringLength(128)]
      MyProperty<string> Address { get; set; }

   }
```

And, of course, I want the validation to act upon the "Value" property.  Looking at the code of the various validation attributes it looked like they were simply calling ToString() to get a value from the object.  I tried overriding ToString() and return Value as a string, but excpetions are being thrown stating that the annotation cannot cast the object (Value) to string (even though the override did just that...?).

I'm trying to avoid writing custom versions of all the various possible validators to accommodate this simple type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look into a source code for StringLength:
https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/StringLengthAttribute.cs

You can see that IsValid casts your value to string, which would fail for your custom class. But you can create your own validation attribute.

Here is an explicit to string casting option for not writing your own validator:

```
public static explicit operator string(MyProperty prop)
{
       return "Stuff you want to return as string";
}
```

Put it inside your MyProperty class.

Comment: Same thing about RegularExpression, but Required you can use if you want to test that your field is not null. All checks you can find in same source code folder.

Comment: Writing custom validators, while is an option, I'd rather avoid since most of the "MyProperty" will be of type string.  Is there no way to override the casting mechanism to have is cast to a string?

Comment: Also for more information look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators

Comment: @JakeShakesworth was it helpful?

Comment: I had to resort to creating new validation attributes by simply extending the existing StringLength, Regex, etc. and overriding the IsValid method.  Trying to use the built-in versions won't work since it appears the explicit cast operation isn't preserved when "MyProperty" is passed into the IsValid method as a plain-old object type.

Comment: Right, didn't think of that. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is not working so why is this an accepted answer?